# When identifying $X$ with $\operatorname{mspec}k[X]$, how do we identify $\phi\colon X\to Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $\phi\colon X\to Y$ is a morphism of affine varieties. It's common place to identify $X$ with the maximal ideals of $k[X]$, by $x\leftrightarrow M_x=\{f\in k[X]:f(x)=0\}$.

What does this mean for $\phi$ after we make this identification? I know there is a comorphism $\phi^\ast\colon k[Y]\to k[X]$, and we get a map on spectra
$$
\operatorname{spec}(k[X])\to\operatorname{spec}(k[Y]):p\mapsto(\phi^\ast)^{-1}(p)
$$

Does this mean we say $\phi(x)=y$ iff in terms of maximal ideals, $M_y\supseteq(\phi^\ast)^{-1}(M_x)$?

I'm curious because sometimes authors will identify the points as maximal ideals, and then say something about $\phi$, but I'm not sure what the relation is between $\phi\colon X\to Y$ and some presumably some corresponding map $\operatorname{mspec}(k[X])\to\operatorname{mspec}(k[Y])$ after identifying the points with maximal ideals.

Comment: More precisely, $\phi(x)=y$ iff $M_y=(\phi^*)^{-1}(M_x)$. It's important that you're dealing with finite type stuff over a field here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring#Jacobson_rings_and_the_Nullstellensatz

Comment: @MattiaTalpo Thanks, so it's fair to say that $\phi$ is now identified as a map $\phi\colon mspec(k[X])\to mspec(k[Y])$ defined by $\phi(x)=\phi(M_x)=(\phi^\ast)^{-1}(M_x)=y=M_y$ after making the identifications?

Comment: Yep. (filling chars)